# Detect multiple keypresses and trigger an action once in p5.js

Tags: javascript, boolean, p5.js, keypress, game-development

I want the user to be able to press <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> **once** and my game should increase the score, not hold it to increase score, similar to when pressing <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> causes a special effect to occur in a game.

This code did not work so I didn't bother to call it fail attempts test.

```js
function keyPressed() {
    if (key == 'a' && key == 'd')
  score += 1;
}
```

This is my first failing attempt:

```js
function keyPressed() {
    if (key == 'a' || key == 'd')
  score += 1;
}
```

This is my second failing attempt.

The reason for it is because when I press 1 button, it still increases the score and when pressing 2 buttons and holding them to increase faster but does not stop, which is not what I have in mind.

Score2keypress.js:

```js
let RightButtom = false;
let LeftButtom = false;

let character = {
  "score": 0
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  // draw score character
  fill(0, 0, 255); //move6
  text("Score: " + character.score, 20, 120);

  // update score increase character
  if (RightButtom) {
    character.score += 1;
  } //move8
  if (LeftButtom) {
    character.score += 1;
  } //move10

  /////////////ScoreExtra
  // show boolean values onscreen for clarity
  textSize(20);
  text("RightButtom = " + RightButtom +
    "\nLeftButtom = " + LeftButtom, 10, 10, width / 2, height / 2);
}

//////////////ScoreExtra

function keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'a') {
    LeftButtom = true;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    RightButtom = true;
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (key == 'a') {
    LeftButtom = false;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    RightButtom = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches. The event-driven approach is using p5's [`keyPressed`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed) and [`keyReleased`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyReleased) callbacks, pulling the key's [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) string from the native `KeyboardEvent` object. Adding and removing these key codes to a `pressed` set lets you implement variants of single-trigger logic.

```js
const character = {score: 0};
const pressed = new Set();

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  textSize(20);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text("Score: " + character.score, 20, 50);
}

function keyPressed(evt) {
  const {code} = evt;

  if (!pressed.has(code)) {
    pressed.add(code);

    if (pressed.has("KeyA") && pressed.has("KeyD")) {
      character.score++;
    }
  }
}

function keyReleased(evt) {
  pressed.delete(evt.code);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you want to detect and take action purely in `draw`, p5.js provides [`keyIsDown`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown) which accepts a parameter [keycode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keycode).

```js
const character = {score: 0};
const pressed = new Set();

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  textSize(20);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text("Score: " + character.score, 20, 50);
  
  if (keyIsDown(65) && keyIsDown(68)) {
    if ((keyIsDown(65) && !pressed.has(68)) ||
        (!pressed.has(65) && keyIsDown(68))) {
      character.score++;
    }

    pressed.add(65);
    pressed.add(68);
  }

  if (!keyIsDown(65)) {
    pressed.delete(65);
  }
  if (!keyIsDown(68)) {
    pressed.delete(68);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

As mentioned, there are multiple behavioral variants you can implement. Here's a variant that prevents retriggers with the same key:

```js
const character = {score: 0};
const pressed = new Set();

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  textSize(20);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text("Score: " + character.score, 20, 50);
  
  if (keyIsDown(65) && !pressed.has(65) && // 'a' and 'd'
      keyIsDown(68) && !pressed.has(68)) {
    character.score++;
    pressed.add(65);
    pressed.add(68);
  }

  if (!keyIsDown(65)) {
    pressed.delete(65);
  }
  if (!keyIsDown(68)) {
    pressed.delete(68);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

In all above cases, the behavior lets the user press and hold one key indefinitely, then press the other. If you want these keys to be pressed on the exact same frame, or within `n` frames, you could remove the key from the set after it's been in there for `n` frames and add it to a `requireRetrigger` set that will prevent it from firing an action until it's been released. [`keyReleased`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyReleased) might be handy here.

Comment: This doesn't work well. Try different combinations of hold/release a/d and see it doesn't register. My solution is cleaner.

Comment: It's supposed to be "stuck". OP wants the action to be taken one time when you push `a` and `d`, right? I'm not sure that resorting to vanilla JS rather than p5 is cleaner.

Comment: If I was a gamer I would expect that `a+d-d+d` should trigger twice. But it's a matter of definition of course

Comment: Added, so OP can pick their behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To detect to keys pressed together you need to monitor their state using `keydown` and `keyup` events.

```js
var obj_down = {}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
  if (obj_down[event.key]) {

    // prevent multiple triggering
    return
  }
  obj_down[event.key] = true;

  if (obj_down["a"] && obj_down["d"]) {
    console.log("a and d were pressed together! score++");
  }
})

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev) {
  delete obj_down[event.key];
})
```

```html
Focus me with mouse then you can press "a" and "d" together
```

Comment: This detects the keys, but OP wants the trigger to occur one time even if the keys are held down. Also, a `Set` would be more idiomatic than an object with boolean values.

Comment: Thanks I'll fix the answer. I prefer to use plain objects as dictionaries.

Comment: It's acting as a set, not a dict (the presence/absence of the value determines the truthiness; the value is just extra cruft to placehold), and the name `arr` is misleading because it's not an array. JS doesn't use `_` in variable names. But just suggestions. I think [`keyIsDown`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown) can be used to natively detect multiple key presses.